# Trying to understand async / await and parallelism

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, parallel-processing

I'm writing an applications which will do an import which can take very long.
In order to speed up the importing process, I've implemented it using the Task Parallel Library, see the code below:

```
var nodes = XmlReaderUtils.EnumerateAxis(reader, new[] { "Node", "ArticleGroup" });

Parallel.ForEach(nodes, element =>
{
    // ToDo: Still write a method to process the "Node", which are "Classifications" here.
    if (element.Name == "Node") { }
    if (element.Name == "ArticleGroup") { new ArticleDataImporter(element).Import(); }
});
```

If I understand the concept correctly, it will create as many threads as possible to process the code inside the Parallel.ForEach as fast a possible (correct me if I'm wrong).

Now, I was browsing on the web and came across some async / await blogpost that serves the same purpose I guess.

I've written an extension method for that one and it looks like the following:

```
public static async Task ForEachAsync<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, Task> body)
{
    var exceptions = new List<Exception>();

    foreach (var item in source)
    {
        try { await body(item); }
        catch (Exception ex) { exceptions.Add(ex); }
    }

    if (exceptions.Any()) { throw new AggregateException(exceptions); }
}
```

Now, if I call this extension method in the following way:

```
var task = nodes.ForEachAsync(async element =>
{
    // ToDo: Still write a method to process the "Node", which are "Classifications" here.
    if (element.Name == "Node") { }
    if (element.Name == "ArticleGroup") { await new ArticleDataImporter(element).Import(); }
});
```

Would that result in the same output as using the TPL?

If not, could someone explain to me what's going on here because I don't quite understand it.

Kind regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ForEachAsync you've written will execute the tasks in sequence. The processing of the second element will not start until the first task has completed.

What happens when you do `await body(item)` in ForEachAsync is that the execution of ForEachAsync is suspended and the calling method will continue executing the statement after `var task = nodes.ForEachAsync`. When `body` completes `ForEachAsync` will resume and continue it's foreach with the second item in the list.

The difference from a regular foreach is that ForEachAsync returns a task, which means that if you do not await it, the method calling ForEachAsync will continue with the next statement before ForEachAsync completes. Hence, you should await that task somewhere in your calling code either by using `await` or `task.Wait()` depending on the behavior you want.

A method implementing parallel foreach could be done like this:

```
public static void ParallelForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, Task> body)
{
    List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();

    foreach (var item in source)
    {
        tasks.Add(body(item));
    }

    Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
}
```

This will run your tasks in parallel and it will wait for all tasks to complete before it returns.

Look at the difference in behavior by running this code:

```
List<int> ints = new List<int> {3, 2, 1};

ints.ForEachAsync(async i =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Task async {0} starting", i);
            await Task.Delay(i*1000);
            Console.WriteLine("Task async {0} done", i);
        }
    ).Wait();

ints.ParallelForEach(async i =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Task parallel {0} starting", i);
            await Task.Delay(i*1000);
            Console.WriteLine("Task parallel {0} done", i);
        });
```

Also try removing the .Wait() from the first `ints.ForEachAsync` call and look at the changed behavior.

You might also want to have a look at this [msdn article explaining async and await](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, this was the answer I was looking for. Why is async / await so difficult :-)

Comment: Just a question. Do you mind adapting your ParallelForEach method to include the AggregateException because that's still not clear to me. I do think I need to create a task that wraps the body call in a try-catch and add it to the exception list, however, not sure about that one.

Comment: You mind explaining why your method for parallel is not made asynchronously?

Comment: The Task.WaitAll will throw an AggregateException if any of the tasks results in an exception. [Task.WaitAll on msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270695%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: The ParallelForEach is not asyncrounous to it's caller because the Task.WaitAll will block until all taks complete. If you want it to be async, change its return type to `Task` instead of `void`. Then replace `Task.WaitAll` with `return Task.WhenAll`. It returns a task that will complete when all the tasks complete. Then the caller will continue processing and can wait for the task to complete when appropriate.

Comment: That's correct, but then I do have an error with the error handling, because the exception does not propagate to the upper await call.

Comment: You have to do `await task` or `Task.Wait()` for the AggregateException to be thrown. Or do I misunderstand your question?

Comment: I'll try to implement it and come back to you.